# Нужна помощь, использую intellij IDEA edu, импорт в классах горит красным. В пом файле зависимости подключены. В чем может быть проблема?

Tags: intellij-idea

[image: Весь импорт горит красным]

[image: В пом файле есть зависимость]

Нужна ваша помощь, все библиотеки подгружаются, в пом файле есть зависимости.

Comment: Для уверенности, в правом меню мавена, кнопки реимпорт и генерейт нажимали ведь?

Comment: Такое иногда бывает, попробуйте `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart`

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1: Правой кнопкой мыши по папке "src", затем выбрать пункт "Mark Directory as", подпункт "Sources Root".
Вариант 2: Пункт меню File - Project Structure. Проверить, подключены ли нужные библиотеки во вкладке Libraries

Comment: Проверил библиотеки, они не подключены. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: В открытом во втором варианте окне "Project Structure" во вкладке "Libraries" нажать на кнопку "+", после чего указать путь до каталога с библиотеками.